# Swift AVQueuePlayer finished playing video

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to get a notification every time a video is finished playing with my `AVQueuePlayer` but currently, this is only working once and then doesn't get called again.

```
func setupVideoPlayer(video: videos) {
    self.player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: video), after: nil)
}

func handlePlayVideo() {
    player.play()
    print(player.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (notification) in
        print("VIDEO FINISHED")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notification.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here,

```
func handlePlayVideo() {
    player.play()
    print(player.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (notification) in
        print("VIDEO FINISHED")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notification.name)
    }
}
```

after first notification is received, you are removing the observer, so It will not observe to same notification second time.

remove the last line :

```
func handlePlayVideo() {
    player.play()
    print(player.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (notification) in
        print("VIDEO FINISHED")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the observer once it's called!

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (notification) in
    print("VIDEO FINISHED")
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notification.name)
}
```